# Django Translations - how to do it efficiently?

Tags: python, django

I have an apphook integrated into a django cms page. Dynamic content from the apps models is shown.

Now I want to pass different fields to the template depending of the language defined by the url e.g. www.mysite.com/en/

my example model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    description_de = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    description_en = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

my example view:

```
def list(request):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
    description = entry.description_de
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'description': description})
```

Now I want to detect the language (from request?) in the view and pass the  field in the correct language to the template. How could I do that?

Or do you suggest a more effective solution?

Comment: You can detect the language with request `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: That is the language the browser requests (modified in browser settings): But I think I need to identify the "/en/" part from the requested URL.. or maybe Django is doing that for me?

Comment: If your user was registered you could for example create a field `country` for him. But else you don't know anything about the actual user except for his request headers. And I believe `Accept-Language` header is just what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect the language with `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` in your views

```
def list(request):
    lang = request.LANGUAGE_CODE
    entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
    description = getattr(entry, 'description_%s' % lang)
    return render(request, 'name.html', {'description': description})
```

you may consider to use [modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) for this use case

Comment: Thanks for your snippet! A very nice way to solve my issue. I will have a look at modeltranslations.